# Programa para mostrar e esconder em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Meu objetivo é fazer um programa que tenha uma lista, e cada vez que o mouse passe por cima do nome dessa lista, ela mostre um conteúdo de uma `div`, mas então usando esse código aqui, criei um vetor pra cada item da lista, mas não to conseguindo fazer com que ele mostre. Alguém pode mostrar o erro ou solução?

```
<blink>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function mostra()
 {
   var arraypilotes=["1","2","3"];
   document.getElementById('arraypilotes[i]').style.display = 'block';  
}  

function esconde()
 { 
    var arraypilotes=["1","2","3"];
    document.getElementById('arraypilotes[i]').style.display = 'none';  
}  
</script>

<a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:mostra();" onmouseout="esconde();">Teste</a>  
<div id="arraypilotes[0]" style="display:none;">Conteudo da DIV</div> 
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:mostra();" onmouseout="esconde();">Teste2</a>  
<div id="arraypilotes[1]" style="display:none;">Conteudo da DIV</div>   
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:mostra();" onmouseout="esconde();">Teste3</a>  
<div id="arraypilotes[2]" style="display:none;">Conteudo da DIV</div>   
</body>
</html>
</blink>
```

Comment: `onmouseover="javascript:mostra();"` deve ser `onmouseover="mostra();"`, o prefixo `javascript:` deve ser usado para executar javascript em links `<a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplificando seu código passe o id da sua div no parâmetro dos método `mostra`e `esconde`.

```html
    <html>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mostra(idDiv) {
                document.getElementById(idDiv).style.display = 'block';
            }

            function esconde(idDiv) {
                document.getElementById(idDiv).style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>

        <a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:mostra('div0');" onmouseout="esconde('div0');">Teste</a>
        <div id="div0" style="display: none;">Conteudo da DIV</div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:mostra('div1');" onmouseout="esconde('div1');">Teste2</a>
        <div id="div1" style="display: none;">Conteudo da DIV</div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:mostra('div2');" onmouseout="esconde('div2');">Teste3</a>
        <div id="div2" style="display: none;">Conteudo da DIV</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: valeeeu cara muito obrigado vai ajudar que so, brigadao mesmo

Answer (score 4):

Que tal usando apenas CSS?

```css
div { display: none }

a:hover + div {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<a href='#!'>Mostrar conteúdo do div 1</a>
<div> conteúdo do div 1</div>

<a href='#!'>Mostrar conteúdo do div 2</a>
<div> conteúdo do div 2</div>
```

Comment: Foste mais rápido ! :) `+1`

Comment: @Sergio aprendendo com tu :p

Comment: valeu cara boa outra solucao alternativa!!