# Identificar elemento onmouseover

Tags: javascript

Quero ao passar num elemento, identificar que tipo de elemente é. Estou a fazer o seguinte exemplo:

```
window.onmouseover =  function(){ mouseOver(e)};
function mouseOver(e) {
  if (e.nodeName === "DIV"){
    alert("it's a div");
 }    
}
```

exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/e5msph9x/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens de usar `e.target` e só depois `nodeName`. `e`  é o objeto evento que tem uma propriedade `target` onde aponta para o elemento DOM, que por sua vez tem uma propriedade com o nome desse tipo de node HTML.

Portanto deve ser `if (e.target.nodeName === "DIV"){`

Não te esqueças também de sempre passar o objeto `e` (evento) nessa cadeia de funções que tens, ou usar a função diretamente ([assim](http://jsfiddle.net/e5msph9x/2/)).

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e5msph9x/1/

Comment: Obrigado @sergio, é possivel em vez de aparecer um alert aparecer uma pequena div  com estilos css por cima do elemente? exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/e5msph9x/3/ Isso é para depois utilisar num gráfico e as div são uns circulos.

Comment: @akm quando dizes por cima queres dizer sobrepondo ou por cima mas não sobrepondo? Sabes que podes fazer isso com CSS também... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64939/129

Comment: Fazer uma label deste genero, http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html, um pouco por cima do circulo.

Comment: @akm assim? -> http://jsfiddle.net/j8znfc1m/

Comment: Obrigado @sergio