# Mostra e esconde conteudo em Div em forma de lista

Tags: javascript, html, div, dropdown

Estou tentando altera esse codigo para que possa esconde e mostra o conteudo em forma de lista.

No momento o codigo mostra o conteudo em videos através da sua id.

```
  <div id="videoGallery">
  <ul>
  <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="">Video 1</span></li>
  <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="">Video 2</span></li>
  <li><span class="vid" data-videoID="">Video 3</span></li>

  <li><span id="close">Fechar Tudo</span></li>
  </ul>



  <style>
  #videoGallery ul {
  list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#videoGallery span {
display: block;
background-color: steelblue;
color: #fff;
font-family: sans-serif;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 4px 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#videoGallery li {
position: relative;
}
span.nowPlaying {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
</style>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>




  <script type="text/javascript">
  var buttons = $('#videoGallery .vid');
  var liHeight = $('#videoGallery li').height();

   buttons.click(function(){
  var videoID = $(this).attr('data-videoID');
  var videos = $('<div id="meuVideo"> <iframe width="560" height="315" src="www.youtube.com/embed/'+ videoID +'?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>');

$('#meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
videos.insertAfter(this).hide().slideDown("fast");
$('<span class="nowPlaying">▼ Reproduzindo ...</span>').insertAfter(this);
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: (videos.offset().top-liHeight)
}, 200);
});

$('#close').click(function(){
$('#meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
});
</script>
```

Gostaria de altera-lo para que o conteudo que esteja dentro da div:

```
    <div class="video">
      Conteudo
     </div>
```

apareça no formato mostra e esconde em forma de lista.

Comment: Veja.http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64935/programa-para-mostrar-e-esconder-em-javascript/64940#64940

Comment: Terceira pergunta essa semana com o mesmo problema, da uma pesquisada antes.

Comment: e também relacionada com - [Adicionar Players em codigo script](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104239). Como o @Huskell já disse, já é a terceira pergunta sobre a mesma coisa. Não duplique perguntas, se as respostas à sua pergunta não eram exatamente aquilo que procurava, tente ser mais especifico nas suas perguntas, edite a pergunta, mas não as duplique (ou neste caso triplique).

Answer (score 0):

Usa esse scrip para Ocultar a div , aonde esta "teste" vc coloca o id da div

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                function mostra() {
                    if (document.getElementById('teste').style.display == 'block'){
                        document.getElementById('teste').style.display = 'none';
                    }else {document.getElementById('teste').style.display = 'block'}
                }

            </script>
```

e no Botão você coloca esse evento :

```
onclick="mostra('teste')"
```